# AWS - EC 2 All of sudden lost access due to No /sbin/init, trying fallback

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my AWS EC2 instance, was locked and lost access from December 6th for an unknown reason, it cannot be an action i did on the EC2, because i was overseas on holidays from December 01st and Came back January 01st, I realized server was lost connection from 6t December and i have no way to connect to the EC2 now on,

EC2 runs on CENTOS 7 and PHP, NGINX, SSHD setup.

When i checked the System Log i see below.

```
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Cleanup udevd DB.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Switch Root.
         Starting Switch Root...
[    6.058942] systemd-journald[99]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
[    6.077915] systemd[1]: No /sbin/init, trying fallback
[    6.083729] systemd[1]: Failed to execute /bin/sh, giving up: No such file or directory
[  180.596117] random: crng init done
```

Any idea on what is the issue will be much appreciated

Comment: This looks like a corrupt root volume. You can try to Stop & Start the instance again (via the web console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Brief, i had to following to recover, The root cause has been that the disk was completely full.

```
) Problem mounting the slaved volume (xfs_admin)
) Not able to chroot the environment (ln -s)
) Disk at 100% (df -h) Removing var/log files
) Rebuilt the initramfs (dracut -f)
) Rename the etc/fstab
) Switched the Slave volume back to original UUID (xfs_admin)
) Configured the Grub to boot the latest version of the kernel/initramfs
) Rebuilt Initramfs and Grub
```